# from flask import Flask command not working

Tags: python, flask, command, pip

I have installed Python 3.5.0, and have successfully downloaded Flask using

```
pip install flask
```

But when I enter the following in command prompt:

```
from flask import Flask
```

I get: 'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Does this have something to do with the Path? How would I go about adjusting it?

Comment: You should  run `from flask import Flask` in a python shell or a python file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write the code in a file and execute it with Python.  You've just typed `from` with some arguments in the Windows shell.  `from` is not a program on your path, so Windows says it doesn't know what you're trying to do.